# Complex conditional formatting based on consecutive cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have values in different cells like this:

```
X   G   43  71  19  T   13  Y   46
21  25  33  67  79  W   56  60  43
71  13  R   31  11  93  85  33  20
67  84  44  63  L   56  61  95  64
45  43  M   30  25  74  43  71  U
28  74  29  58  54  74  68  64  22
```

I want to apply a conditional formatting when appears 43 following by 71, highlighting both in yellow and if that happens, highlight
in red the following 5 'consecutive' cells of the block of values. If it is less complex, could be highlighted with the same color
43,71 and the following 5 cells.

I've tried using this formula for conditional formatting but doesn't work.

```
=AND(A1="43",B1="71",C1:G1<>"")
```

The output I'm looking for is like this:

[image]

Can this be done or only with vba? thanks

Comment: with 6 OR Statements you can do an ugly but working excel formula. Or if you are allowed to use an auxillary column the formula can be much easier.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with CF, since you want to maintain the previous/next relationship when the data breaks into different rows. That will be very difficult to address with relative cell references. Might be easier to write a quick VBA loop.

Comment: Hmm, originally voted to close since it was asking about conditional formatting, which belongs on SU (retracted after a re-read). Suggest you ask for a *specific* VBA solution if it can only be done with VBA, that will make it more applicable to this site.

Comment: @Andreas Hi, how would be the use of auxiliary column? What would be the idea?

Comment: What happens if 43 & 71 are found in last few cells e.g. H6 & I6 in above snapshot?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij If 43 71 appears at the end is the same, highlight in yellow, even there are no following 5 cells.

Comment: @GerCas, the idea is that you have a formula in the auxiallary showing where your 7 cell long sequence starts, essentialy and if statement first checking the boarder and then the normal range like Match(43, ...)=1+Match(71, ...) after you have the start of the sequence you can check if the current column number is wihin start of sequence and start of sequence + 7

Comment: @Andreas I get the idea, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, The execution time seems to be faster.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB() As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngU As Range
    Dim blYes As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim s, e
    
    s = Timer
    Set rngDB = Range("a1", "i6")
    
    rngDB.Interior.Color = xlNone
    For Each rng In rngDB
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vDB(1 To n)
        Set vDB(n) = rng
    Next rng
    
    For i = 1 To n - 5
        If vDB(i) = 43 And vDB(i + 1) = 71 Then
            blYes = True
            Set rngU = Nothing
            For j = 2 To 6
                If vDB(i + j) = "" Then
                    blYes = False
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If rngU Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngU = vDB(i + j)
                    Else
                        Set rngU = Union(vDB(i + j), rngU)
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            If blYes Then
                Union(vDB(i), vDB(i + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 237, 125)
                rngU.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 203, 203)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    e = Timer
    MsgBox e - s
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for the help. I've tried with 64 cols and 1700 rows and it finishes in less than 0.7 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that it would be diabolically complex to do with formulas. Here is a VBA alternative (noting that it doesn't reset the fill color for non-affected cells between runs):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatCells()

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim ColorExtras As Long
    
    Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I6")
    
    ColorExtras = 0
    For Each CurrentCell In SourceRange
        
        ' Track if the extra five cells needs to be colored red ... using a countdown
        If ColorExtras > 0 Then
            CurrentCell.Interior.Color = rgbRed
            ColorExtras = ColorExtras - 1
        End If
        
        ' Check if the cell is 71 and the prior cell is 43 .. and if so, color both orange
        If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
            If CurrentCell.Value = 71 And LastCell.Value2 = 43 Then
                LastCell.Interior.Color = rgbOrange
                CurrentCell.Interior.Color = rgbOrange
                ColorExtras = 5
            End If
        End If
        
        Set LastCell = CurrentCell
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It gives correct output and I was able to customize it to test actual data.